# Can ffmpeg extract multiple parts of a video file in a single command?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I have some huge MPEG files that is 24 hours long, and I need to extract a few parts (about 30 minutes each) of it into frame sequences (still images). I tried using commands like following:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpeg -ss 4:00:00 -to 4:30:00 outpath1\%05d.png
ffmpeg -i input.mpeg -ss 6:00:00 -to 6:30:00 outpath2\%05d.png
...
```

But it seems that each time it is executed, ffmpeg scans the file from the beginning, causing the process to be very slow.

For example, when I execute the above commands to extract the part of 4:00:00-4:30:00, ffmpeg will scan from 0:00:00 to 4:00:00, start extracting the image sequence, and stop at 4:30:00; and then I execute another command to extract the part of 6:00:00-6:30:00, and ffmpeg scans from 0:00:00 again to 6:00:00, and then start extracting.

So I wanted to simplify this process to save time. Is there a way to extract multiple parts in a single command? Like scans from 0:00:00 to 4:00:00, start extracting to 4:30:00, stop extracting and continue scanning to 6:00:00, and start extracting again...until the last part. Can ffmpeg do this?

Comment: move `-ss ... -to ...` before `-i input`

Comment: You can also remove `-to` and use `-t` and give it a value of total duration(from start-to-end), exp :- before `-ss 4:00:00 -to 4:30:00`, after `-ss 4:00:00 -t 30:00`